# FlushMode in JPA with Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have some problems with FlushMode.AUTO in JPA/Hibernate, because i need change a value of a JavaBean and process a special validation. If validation is ok the bean is updated in DB, if validation fail the bean cannot be updated, like this:

```
 MyBean bean = getBeanFromDB();

 bean.setNewNumber(12);

 //Before call isValid the bean already updated in DB
 if (isValid(bean)){
   update(bean);
 }
```

But before validation begins, the Hibernate process the AUTO-UPDATE in my Bean and i don't wanna it. So my solution is setting FlushMode.COMMIT in JPA, but i'm using Spring and i don't know how can i do it in CONFIGURATION (XML) mode.

Answer (score -1):

I see two options:

- use [bean validation](http://hibernate.org/validator/) (aka JSR-303) and its [JPA integration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-integration.html#d0e5006) to ensure automatic validity
- use [@PrePersist and @PreUpdate events](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Events) to have your validation logic invoked automatically

Comment: But the problem is not just the validation proccess, the main problem is the auto-update from hibernate. Because use can click CANCEL in any moment